# Spring boot entityManager не строит таблицы БД

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
Application properties:

# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/post
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username = *******
spring.datasource.password = *******

# JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.show-sql = false

@EnableAsync
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
      private static final Logger log =       
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);
        private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS =   
           {"classpath:/static/",
            "classpath:/public/","classpath:/templates/"};

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

           return (container -> {

           ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,    
           "/error/401/");
           ErrorPage error403Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,   
           "/error/403/");
           ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 
           "/error/404/");
           ErrorPage error500Page = new   
           ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/error/500/");
           ErrorPage registrationException = new 
           ErrorPage(RegistrationException.class,
           "/error/registrationPageError/");

            container.addErrorPages(error401Page, error403Page, error404Page, 
            error500Page);
            });
           }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
      Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
      connector.setScheme("http");
      connector.setSecure(false);
      connector.setPort(33950);
      connector.setRedirectPort(33443);

        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };

        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
        return tomcat;
    }

     @Bean
     public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory
     (DataSource dataSource,JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter){

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory 
                        = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("ua.kiev.dobrobutZahyst");

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                    CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ShaPasswordEncoder getShaPasswordEncoder(){
        return new ShaPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text","plain", Charset.forName("utf-8"))));
        converters.add(stringConverter);
    }

    @Bean
    public Gson gson(){
        final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(InputPost.class, new InputPostGsonConverter());
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(OutputPost.class, new OutputPostGsonConverter());
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(CorporationPost.class, new CorporationPostGsonConverter());
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(File.class, new FileGsonConverter());
        gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();

        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

При старте приложения построение таблиц пропускается и стартует приложение. Exception никакой не выскакивает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: для начала проверить подключение к БД

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko все отлично работает...Проблем только в том, что не переключается автогенирация таблиц.

Comment: а в бине что написано? можете показать?

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko Это все, что касается базы данных.

Comment: @НиколайЕгоров а как же аннотации над конфигурационным классом `@EnableJpaRepositories @EnableTransactionManagement` ? Как адаптер настроен, datasource? Проверить Ваш вопрос нельзя, добавьте минимальный пример, который можно воспроизвести.

Comment: @MrFylypenko это же Spring Boot. Он же из контекста вытягивает. Ну, я выставил весь файл-конфигурацию.